# Using main in a Haskell file

Tags: haskell, ghc, side-effects

I've done a fair bit of programming in haskell using GHCI however our next assignment requires us to use just GHC to compile and test our code.

Because of how ghci works compared to ghc you apparently need to use a `main` function and the ghc looks for this function in your code.

My question is, if Haskell promotes type safety and no side-effects unless within an `IO` action, why does the main part of any haskell program have to be an `IO` action?

Forgive me if I'm not understanding something fundamental, I just couldn't find any resources which ultimately explains this.

Comment: Simon Peyton-Jones on IO: " I/O is the raison d’etre of every program.  — a program that had no observable effect whatsoever (no input, no output) would not be very useful "

Comment: Note that whenever you are in GHCi and do something like `3<Enter>` you are in essence writing, and then running, the program `main = print 3`.

Comment: Note that, while this question is very simple, it's one of those that's *so* simple that nobody has actually explained it anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your `main` function is not an `IO` action, then all it can do is produce a result.  Since Haskell is lazy, this (usually) means that it just produces a promise that the computation will be performed, but it won't compute it until it needs to be used.  Since the usual way to ensure something is computed is to print that value out, or send it over a network, save it to disk, or use it for some other kind of IO, your result won't be computed and the program would simply exit.  Imagine a fake program like

```
main :: Int
main = 1 + 1
```

Suppose you could compile and run this, what would you expect to happen?  Nothing gets printed, nothing is asking for the result of `main`, all that Haskell can do with this is create the promise that `1 + 1` will be computed at some point then exit the program.  Basically, you can't do anything interesting at the top level without IO, and since we want programs to do interesting things we need our top level to be an `IO` action.

Comment: This this beautiful. Perfectly explained! Now to try and get rid of all the type matching errors I have to try and get my results into an IO () ;)

Comment: @Bradley If your program is just computing something then printing out the answer your `main` would ideally be along the lines of `main = print answer`, with `answer = <some expression>`.  If you know all your inputs ahead of time then you can supply them all inside `answer`.  If you need to use command line arguments or read from a file, you should write your code so that all the work is done with pure functions, and then your main might be `main = do { filecontents <- readFile "somefile.txt"; print $ doSomethingWithFileContents filecontents }`

Comment: I created a type and just wanted my main to print the type itself as I am deriving show, just to get a feel with using haskell without ghci. I just have no idea how to convert my type into an IO action!

Comment: Just do `print myValue` where `myValue :: MyType`.  The `print` function will call `show` on your value, and if you're `deriving Show` everything should just work.

Comment: ' .: createDirectory: invalid argument (Invalid argument) ' is the error I get from calling print myTemp, I'm close to giving up! Hahahah

Comment: @Bradley I would recommend asking a separate question with the specific code you're struggling with, I don't know what that error means without context.

Answer (score 4):

Put simply, running a program *is* a side-effect. This is why the top-level function is an I/O action.

An ideal Haskell program is a large chunk of pure code with a thin I/O "skin" around it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's pretty straightforward - ultimately, you need every program to do IO at the top level - otherwise how would you know if it did anything at all, or - how useful would it be?  So you must have either console I/O, network I/O, disk I/O, or something similar.  I don't see how you could get around that.

Comment: program have an exit status which could be seen as an output without side effect. I mean, `main` in C takes a list of string and return an Int. A program could process the argument and return an Int without side effect (and still be usefull).

Comment: I suppose that, assuming you were able to get to command line arguments without doing IO...  Can you?

Comment: As you said "you need every program to do IO at the top level" but that doesn't have to be at the *normal* haskell. I mean, at the end of the day,  an 'IO ()' doesn't do any IO (or even anything) until some sort of god take this *action* and decide to execute it. This god is the layer between your haskell program and you system. Executing `main :: IO()` is just a convention and one could imagine that this *god* could take a pure`main :: [String] -> Int` call with the arguments on the command line and return it's result. The final program would you IO, but not the Haskell part.